# Missing DbProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

C#; .NET Core 2.2; Visual Studio 2019

I get the following exception on the first DB query in my app.

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

That method looks like:

```
public List<string> GetList() 
{
    try 
    {
        using (var db = new CommoditiesContext())
        {
            var list = (from commodity in db.Commodity
                        where commodity.DateObsolete.Equals(null)
                        select commodity.Name.Trim().ToUpper()).OrderBy(a => a).ToList();

            return list;
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new Exception("GetList: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I created the model involved via:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=MyDB.company.com;Initial Catalog=THINGS;Integrated Security=True" -Context CommoditiesContext -Schemas "dbo" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\Commodities
```

The `CommoditiesContext.cs` file is auto generated and has the method:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            //warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=MyDB.company.com;Initial Catalog=THINGS;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
```

This method appears to only be called when the query above is executed.  The `CommoditiesContext` class is not instantiated as far as I can tell.

As the warning comment in the `OnConfiguring()` method says, it is a bad idea to have connection strings in the code.  Cool, I dig that.  I have commented out the `OnConfiguring()` method and instead am trying to use:

```
        services.AddDbContext<CommoditiesContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommoditiesContext")
            )
        );
```

in my `startup.cs` file.

I run web app locally and can put a break point on the `services` line and see the correct connection string going in.  I break on the query above but generate the exception at the top.

For some reason the `service` version is not found by the query.

I do a bunch of googling and re-enable the `OnConfiguring()` method.  Looks like I need to pull in the connection string in the `OnConfiguring()` method.

The majority of solutions I found say to add:

```
public class CommoditiesContext : DbContext {
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public CommoditiesContext(IConfiguration config) {
        _config = config;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then use:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("CommoditiesContext"));
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that this auto generated class does not appear to be instantiated in the process of calling `OnConfiguring()` so `_config` is null.

What should I be doing?

Comment: I'm missing a link to you config / settings file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is set up, you need to inject it.
Here is an example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly CommoditiesContext db;

    public MyController(CommoditiesContext db)
    {
        // db is 'automatically' created and given to you.
        this.db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetList()
    {
        var list = (from commodity in db.Commodity
                    where commodity.DateObsolete.Equals(null)
                    select commodity.Name.Trim().ToUpper()).OrderBy(a => a).ToList();

        return this.Ok(list);
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

## Addition:

If you have multiple db contexts, you can add multiple like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<CommoditiesContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(
      Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommoditiesContext")
    )
);

services.AddDbContext<AnotherDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(
      Configuration.GetConnectionString("AnotherDbContext")
    )
);
```

usage:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly CommoditiesContext comDb;
    private readonly AnotherDbContext anoDb

    public MyController(
              CommoditiesContext comDb,
              AnotherDbContext anoDb)
    {
        this.comDb = comDb;
        this.anoDb = anoDb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked at the doc link you shared.  If i have more than one active DB would I then pass in the whole `IConfiguration` object to find all the contexts?

Comment: @7Reeds You have multiple databases for the same context?

Comment: Maybe I am back to missing something fundamental... I have more than one db context. More than one of them are being used in the active Controller.  In the example above I am only using one context.  I assumed I would be able to extrapolate how to use more than one.

I have just tried the `IConfiguration` thing.  That gives me the general config but not the db contexts, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @7Reeds Just inject multiple db contexts. That's why adding a db context is generic. I've udpated my answer.